# Array of struct: set all empty attributes ([]) to NaN

Tags: matlab

I have an array of structs and would like to set all empty attributes to NaN:

```
structArray = 
29x1 struct array with fields:
    value
    id
```

How do I set all struct.value attributes to NaN, if they are empty?

If they are empty the conversion `[structArray.value]` omits the empty elements...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given this:

```
x(29).id = [];
x(29).value = [];
```

You can set the value of all `.id` fields like this

```
[x.value] = deal(nan);
```

To set only a particular subset of values define a mask of values to set and then use it in your assignment statement:

```
maskEmptyId = arrayfun(  @(a)isempty(a.id),  x  );
[x(maskEmptyId).id] = deal(nan);
```

Comment: It also works as one liner: 
[x(arrayfun(@(a)isempty(a.id),  x)).id]=deal(nan);

Answer (score 0):

As @Pursuit explained there is an excellent way to replace the empty fields with NaNs

However, you may also be interested in a different approach.

Instead of replacement in hindsight you may be able to prevent the empty spots to occur in the first place. Assuming they are empty because nothing has been assigned to them, you can simply initialize your struct with NaNs.

For example:

```
structArray = struct ('id',[],'value',NaN)
```

Calling this before you assign anything to structArray would initialize the value field with NaN, but will still initialize the id to be empty.